# How can I add an attachment created on the canvas inside a .setImage()?

Tags: canvas, discord, discord.js

I was wondering how I can add an attachment created on the canvas and embed the image in a .setImage is it possible?

- Discordjs version v14

I tried the following:

```js
const attach = new AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer(), { name: "image.png"})//exemple

interaction.reply({ embeds: [new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("title cool").setColor("5865F2").setImage(attach)]})
```

But it didn't work, does anyone know how this might work?

Comment: Try just `canvas.toBuffer()`

Comment: I don't think that's it, the canvas creates the normal image, but I want to put this image in the .setImage()

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
const attach = new AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer(), { name: "image.png"})//exemple

interaction.reply({ embeds: [new EmbedBuilder().setTitle("title cool").setColor("5865F2").setImage("attachment://image.png")] , files: [attach ]})
```

Docs : https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#using-an-embed-object